# What is default font used in android studio ? Also, which default font displays in android device after debugging code in device?

Tags: android, fonts

What is default font used in android studio?
Which font is displayed in mobile after debugging android app?

Comment: To answer your question roboto. Please refer android documentation before posting or your question is bound to get downvoted..

Comment: If i change Roboto from setting the Android Studio font will change but not display on device, I want to change the font which will display on device with android default fonts.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml this will help u..

Comment: I dont want to use custom font.

Comment: lol.. check properly they have downloadable google fonts as well.. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts

Comment: This one help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Default font used in android is Roboto. You may search for it on the internet.

Comment: If i change Roboto from setting the Android Studio font will change but not display on device, I want to change font which display in device with android default fonts.